# Seeking name credits for pulp SF artists

Tags: art, pulp

I'm trying to identify a few artists whose work appeared in SF pulps currently in the public domain, but whose name credits did not appear in the original issue.  I have their signatures but not their full names.  I wonder if anyone here might know...?

The artists I'm trying to identify are:

**DIEHL** - illo for "Bolden's Pets" by Floyd L. Wallace, appeared in Galaxy Science Fiction, October, 1955

**Kramer** - illo for "The Repairman" by Harry Harrison, appeared in Galaxy, February 1958

**Rogers** - illo for "Temple Trouble" by H. Beam Piper, appeared in Astounding Science Fiction, April, 1951.  I suspect this may be Hubert Rogers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **DIEHL** - illo for "Bolden's Pets" by Floyd L. Wallace, appeared in [*Galaxy Science Fiction*, October, 1955](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58624) [available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v11n01_1955-10#page/n79/mode/2up)].

The [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?88545) does not know his full name; it lists some of his other works.

> **Kramer** - illo for "The Repairman" by Harry Harrison, appeared in [*Galaxy*, February 1958](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58494) [available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v15n04_1958-02#page/n65/mode/2up)].

Frank George Kramer, 1905–1993; see [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?115483), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Kramer_(artist)), [Pulp Artists](http://www.pulpartists.com/Kramer.html).

> **Rogers** - a bunch of illoes for "Temple Trouble" by H. Beam Piper, appeared in [*Astounding Science Fiction*, April, 1951](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57389) [available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v47n02_1951-04_Gorgon776#page/n5/mode/2up)]. I suspect this may be Hubert Rogers.

Reginald Hubert Rogers, 1898-1982; see [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1245), [Pulp Artists](http://www.pulpartists.com/Rogers.html), [The Encyclopedia of Science Fiction](http://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/rogers_hubert), [SciFiGuy.ca](http://www.scifiguy.ca/2008/07/hubert-rogers-1898-1982.html).

Comment: That was quick!  Thank you for introducing me to the isfdb!